# The EntityKey property can only be set, LINQ2Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm having an odd problem, I can't get an object from the DB and then reattach it.  I have written code like this for other projects but for some odd reason it throws the following error in this application:

**System.InvalidOperationException: The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null.**

here is my code:

```
        Entities.Customer customer;
        using (var context = new XXEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<Entities.Customer> query = from a in context.Customers select a;
                query = query.Where(c => c.CODE == "003046");
            customer = query.ToList()[0];
        }


        using (var context = new XXEntities())
        {
            context.Customers.AddObject(customer);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: May be a better option would be to leave the record attached. Do all your business logic elsewhere, and then, when you have all the changes you want to make, pass the object that contains the updated data to a method where you query the DB, make the changes, and save the changes, all in the same method so that the record is always attached. Doing it your way will lead to problems later, at some point.

Comment: I should have given more context to the question, sorry, what i'm doing is the following: GET OBJECT -> PARSE OBJECT TO DTO -> PASS DTO via WS -> MODIFY DTO -> PASS DTO BACK via WS -> REMAP DTO TO ENTITY -> SAVE ENTITY.  The problem is I loose all the related LINQ2Entities stuff to know if the object is new or been modified.

Comment: It may work the other way around: Attach a new object with Id=null. Not entirely sure though.

Comment: Think of ONE method: 1) GET OBJECT, 2) INSTANTIATE WORKER CLASS, 3) PASS OBJECT TO WORKER CLASS (here do all complex business logic) AND RETURN UPDATED DATA, 4) UPDATE OBJECT WITH UPDATED DATA, 5) SAVE CHANGES. You might do step 4 in another class as well but you're still in the same method; that way, you can always reattach the object, handle concurrency (what if 2 users open the same record?) and maintain relational integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2nd block,

```
    using (var context = new XXEntities())
    {
      //context.Customers.AddObject(customer);
        context.Customers.Attach(customer);  
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

`EntitySet.Add()` means add a *new* object. You want to add an *existing* object.

Comment: Just an extra subquestion, but doesn't Linq2EF require you to detach it from the other context first?

Comment: @Silvermind : the using in the first half should take care of that. The 1st context is disposed.

Comment: Thanks. I could have remembered wrong but in the other thing:) Linq2SQL I thought it was required, therefore my question.

Comment: Yeah I found that one, but i thought LINQ2Entities wwas smart enuf not to have to write that type of code?\